# Emmet in Visual Studio Code to add test text with numbers inside incremented

Tags: visual-studio, emmet

I want to make a list of test emails to test a function

Array("test1@email.com", "test2@email.com");

I want to make about 2000 entries on this Array with the email addresses including an incrementing number, can I do this easily with Emmet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this script:

```
Array("test{1..2000}@email.com");
```

Comment: as well:
`const emails = Array.from({ length: 2000 }, (_, index) => \`test${index + 1}@email.com\`);`